# after fetching data from database how to slide in div

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to find how to slide block of data after fetching it from database.
I tried lot but didn't get the result.please help me to find out the solution
here is my code

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php 
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db="lalcoresidency";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);

if(!$conn){
    die("connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<?php
$query="select * from testimonial order by r_id desc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <li>
    <?php echo $row['review'];?>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').carousel({
      interval: 3200
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
```

It already takes my time but i didn't get the solution .this code only show the data line by line

```
my code output
"Loving Staff Welcoming and helpful... Kind and welcome the food is great. Breakfast included."
"Total value for money."
"Excellent facilities with good location and very co-operative and efficient staff."
"Accommodation worth the money paid for... Staff were very helpful and in-house car hire rates were so reasonable."
"An excellent stay... Loved the stay and definitely look forward to keep going back for our next stay."
```

It showing data one by one .but i want to show first lines of data then after sliding it need to show second line.then after slide third line.
please help me to find the solution

Comment: Where is `<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">` closing ?

Comment: after while closing bracket..

Comment: It's not in the code which you provided.

Comment: yeah..after copying it deleted by i tried to put the div after while closing bracket but it giving the same answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because .carousel is not defined in jQuery.

It's an plugin for jQuery where you can download from their website.

https://plugins.jquery.com/jcarousel/

Also don't forget to close `<div>` and `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery by itself does not provide a `.carousel`-function, what plugin are you using for that?

Also try using the console to find errors with the javascript ([Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console), [Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console))

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the code first, It's wrong way of programming. Just use the code below, it works perfectly.

Always try to seprate code logic from html. Create functions to handle the code logic.

**Sample corrected code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testimonials</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.1/flexslider.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>


        <?php
        $dbConnectionObject = getConnection('localhost', 'root', '', 'lalcoresidency');
        if ($dbConnectionObject != false) {

            //Get all data for slides
            $slides = getAllTestimonialsReviews($dbConnectionObject);


            //Check if slides count greater thab zero
            if (count($slides) > 0) {
                ?>
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">

                        <?php
                        foreach ($slides as $slide) {
                            ?>
                            <li><?php echo $slide['review']; ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script>

            (function ($) {
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        animationLoop: true,
                        itemWidth: 200,
                        itemMargin: 5
                    });
                });

            }(jQuery));
        </script>
    </body>


    <?php
     // Turn on error reporting 
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    //Get database connection object
    function getConnection($host, $user, $pass, $databasename) {

        //Check empty
        if (empty($host) || empty($user) || empty($pass) || empty($databasename)) {
            die("Invalid db connection parameters ");
        }

        //vars
        $servername = $host;
        $username = $user;
        $password = $pass;
        $db = $databasename;

        //conenction object
        $connectionObject = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

        if (!$connectionObject) {
            die("connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        return $connectionObject;
    }

    //Get all testimonials
    function getAllTestimonialsReviews($connectionObject = null) {

        //empty check
        if (empty($connectionObject)) {
            die("No conenction object in getALLTestimonialsReviews function");
        }

        //Query
        $query = "select `review` from testimonial order by r_id desc";

        //query result set
        $result = mysqli_query($connectionObject, $query);

        $resultSet = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            //grab all results in array
            $resultSet[] = $row;
        }


        //return result
        return $resultSet;
    }
```

Comment: kapil .your code showing ..Invalid db connection parameters...errors

Comment: @nushrat You just need to check that if there are correct details are used for db connection. I just copied from your code, And i have tested this code locally by creating database and tables, it is working perfectly. Just check the line below, if these details are correct as per your configuration.




$dbConnectionObject = getConnection('localhost', 'root', '', 'lalcoresidency');